# FriendPickerSample doesn't show my friends

Tags: java, facebook

I am testing this sample from the Facebook SDK, but don't appear any friends... it says: "  "

When I click Pick Friends, a pop up window shows:
" FriendPickerSample would like to access your public profile and friend list"

And I click "OK", but nothing happens it keeps showing only the string ""

Do you guys have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I didn't had the key hash registed on facebook app developer, neither had the app_id on the strings xml file.
Thanks all anyways